# How to update carousel view in c# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, carousel

I have a **carousel view** displaying a list of images, and this list will change, and I can't make the carousel view adding or deleting the images.

```
XAML : 
 <CarouselView x:Name="main_carousel">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
 </CarouselView>
```

My list of images's path is added to the item source in the constructor of the main page

```
C# : 
public static List<string> imagesList;

public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            imagesList = new List<string>();
            main_carousel.ItemsSource = imagesList;
        }
```

At first the carousel is empty, but then I add some paths to my list, like this for instance :

```
C# :
public void addElementToMainCarousel()
        {
            imagesList.add(absolute_path + "myImage1.jpg");            
            imagesList.add(absolute_path + "myImage2.jpg");
        }
```

The carousel view doesn't display anything if I add the paths in the list afterwards. But it works if I add the paths in the list before the first `main_carousel.ItemsSource = imagesList;` .

I tried to re-set the ItemsSource like this :

```
C# :
 public void addElementToMainCarousel()
        {
            imagesList.add(absolute_path + "myImage1.jpg");            
            imagesList.add(absolute_path + "myImage2.jpg");
            main_carousel.ItemsSource = imagesList;
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to force refresh of the carousel view or do you know anything that can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the CarouselView won't re-draw itself on screen even if you update your `imagesList`. You need to re-assign `CarouselView.ItemSource` property with a new `List<string>` or `Array` containing your updated data. Please, see a sample below :

```
 myCarouselView.ItemSource = imageslist.ToArray();
```

This works for me as `ToArray()` method returns a new object with the updated data, copied from the previous `List`.

Comment: wow the deeper I get into Xamarin the more I appreciate Ionic

Comment: I get an error when I try to use ToArray() like that.  I even tried creating the list from scratch but it had no effect on the refresh.  I have to scroll between the images and the change takes effect without doing this.  It would be nice if the change were immediate without scrolling but it is better than nothing.

Comment: What error do you get @charlesyoung ?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
I had to go back and recreate it.  Here is the statement: MyWaypoints = waypointModels.ToArray(); - Both of these are of type List.  I can assign one to the other but if I use ToArray() to create a new List it gives the error. Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLE.Client.ViewModels.WaypointModel[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BLE.Client.ViewModels.WaypointModel>' BLE.Client C:\Users\charl\source\repos\GitHub\gammaDogMobileApp\Source\BLE.Client\BLE.Client\ViewModels\TourViewModel.cs 359 Active

Comment: The original author used a List of string for which an implicit conversion to array (and vice versa) is defined. You are using a list of a custom type (`WaypointModel`) so you must either (1) define a conversion method for go from list <-> array, (2) you can dismiss the call to `ToArray()` all together and try a deep copy of the original list in a new one, or (3) use an `ObservableCollection` that should handle the changes for you (see second answer on this thread).

Comment: The more I use Xamarin, the more I believe that it is a unfinished project.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to use a list that binds both the view and the viewmodel, you must implement ObservableCollection, not a list.
ObservableCollection reflects your changes from side to side.

```
ObservableCollection<string> myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
mylist.Add(yourString);
listview.itemSource = mylist;
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried that, and I still have the same problem. Thank for your help tho.

Comment: Hey José, I've tried again, and it works ! Idk why it didnt work at first. Thank you again !

Comment: hahahaha
Famous Double Check.
Whenever something does not work, do Clean / Rebuild and try again.
90% of the time some magic happens and everything works again.